# In python, how to solve logarithm equation (x*logx)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code for solving below logarithm equation in python.

**x*log_2(x) + (1-x)*log_2(1-x) + U = 0**

log_2 is Base-2 logarithm function and U is a constant number (i.e., 0.9)

and solution 'x' will be between 0~1

I had made a code like below.

```
import math
from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq, log

x = Symbol('x')        
equation = x*log(x)/log(2)+(1-x)*log(1-x)/log(2) + 0.9
solve(equation,x)
```

But,because of error for 
**NotImplementedError: multiple generators [x, log(1 - x), log(x)]** , I can't solve that equation.

Also, I had tried to use scipy.optimize like below code

```
import scipy.optimize
import math
from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq

x = Symbol('x')     
scipy.optimize.fsolve(x*math.log2(x)+(1-x)*math.log2(1-x) + 0.9,0.5)# 0.5 is guess value
```

But, this code also makes a error for **TypeError: can't convert expression to float**

How can I solve or approximate that equation in python??
Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: try using `sympy.log` instead of `math.log2`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x*np.log2(x)+(1-x)*np.log2(1-x) + 0.9

result = scipy.optimize.fsolve(myfunc, x0=0.3)
```

`scipy.optimize.fsolve` takes a function with at least one positional argument, which is the variable you need to estimate to find the roots of the function. `x0=0.3` is the starting estimate. Do not start with `x0=0` because it forces your script to divide by zero. Values `x0>1` will crash as well, because it yields negative logarithms for `log2(1-x)`.

Running the script, however, I get different results for different starting conditions:

```
for x0 in np.arange(0.05, 1.0, 0.05):
    result = scipy.optimize.fsolve(myfunc, x0=x0)
    print("Starting estimate: {:3.2f}, result: {:5.3f}".format(x0, result[0]))

>> Starting estimate: 0.05, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.10, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.15, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.20, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.25, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.30, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.35, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.40, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.45, result: 0.316
Starting estimate: 0.50, result: 0.500
Starting estimate: 0.55, result: 0.684
Starting estimate: 0.60, result: 0.684
Starting estimate: 0.65, result: 0.684
Starting estimate: 0.70, result: 0.684
Starting estimate: 0.75, result: 0.684
Starting estimate: 0.80, result: 0.684
Starting estimate: 0.85, result: 0.684
Starting estimate: 0.90, result: 0.684
Starting estimate: 0.95, result: 0.684
```

I recommend usage of `numpy` for mathematical expressions, like `np.log2` for the Base-2 logarithm of x instead of the math package.

Comment: You're welcome! If this solved your problem, you may want to consider to give +1 and check it as the accepted answer. You can also wait for others to come up with more ideas. Good luck with your work